# Should I edit the expletives out of a question's code example where the answers reproduce the word?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

I ran across [a well-scored question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668032/how-to-call-the-overridden-method-of-superclass?rq=1) containing a word which I would consider at least vulgar while browsing Stack Overflow.

I know that [expletives are not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233). I'm personally not offended by people using language like this, but I know some people are. Also, it just doesn't strike me as fitting the vibe of Stack Overflow.

I was about to go ahead and edit it, but I have two concerns. The first is that the consensus seems to be

> "This example is awesome"

I cannot use quotation marks strongly enough around this. Is it? Is anyone other than children impressed by swearing? It's just unnecessary. What was wrong with 'drink'? Still, it's received a lot of upvotes and has been answered by several people who had the rep to edit it if they'd wanted. They presumably thought it was fine.

The second concern I have is that there are numerous answers and the majority have copy and pasted the word from the question. These would need to be edited as well.

What should I do?

Comment: FWIW, when someone finds an example "awesome" just because it has an expletive in it, I also find myself questioning their age and/or level of intelligence. Perhaps that's unfair but it's the case.

Comment: Edit both the question and the answer but make sure you keep consistency. There's really no need to have that particular word in no matter how funny a twelve year old might find it. I myself don't find it offensive but this is a professional site and I wouldn't mouth off like that in a professional capacity.

Comment: Also don't forget to flag the "Hahaha! This example is awesome!" comment as "Too chatty". Even if that example were awesome, we don't need comments to emphasize that. That's just noise.

Comment: What was wrong with 'drink'? Nothing really, but based on most cats I've seen, it probably should have been changed to 'sleep' instead.

Comment: I agree with your edit, but it would've been a good idea to link to this post and write what was being fixed in the edit summary -_-

Comment: I find your changes to be immaterial to the code or it's purpose, and only tend to civilise the discourse.  In fact, your edits help eliminate the distraction that I immediately felt upon reading the original.  Without the unnecessary expletive, reading the question was actually much more clear, and the example code was simpler to read without the distraction.

Comment: "Is anyone other than children impressed by swearing?"  Yes--at least biologically.  Mentally, on the other hand....

Comment: I had almost forgotten, but [the last time someone asked about cleaning up after pooping cats, it didn't go as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215045/why-is-a-question-about-measuring-cat-feces-an-audit-for-close-votes), so good job there.

Comment: I feel this is a question that requires oppinions.  I like to put in $#@$#!@ a few now and then.  Make up your mind.

Comment: This title sounds a little like "I want to edit the [expletive] out the question".

Comment: The problem I see with the edit is, you've lost the implied input/output metaphor.

Comment: @jonp that wasn't relevant to the question. In fact there's no reason to have two methods at all. One demonstrates the point perfectly well.

Comment: @Michael fun fact the one and only Mr Skeet also edit the deleted answers to comply with your edits. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15668230/5292302 (keep the link you will be able to see it when you hit 10K)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If the expletive is not essential to the question (say, the question is about filtering expletives, but doesn't really need examples of said expletives) and you believe some people will be offended by it, edit it out.

---

Don't forget - Stack Overflow is used by many in a professional environment - the question you linked - using those expletives is not particularly needed nor is it professional looking. I'd edit those to something different while keeping the meaning of the question the same.

Comment: Thanks. The cat has now been house-trained.

Comment: @Michael And hydrated as well. Good job!

Comment: @Keiwan: ***Hydrated?!***

Comment: @BoltClock This? https://swervy.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/hydra_cat.jpg

Answer (score 22):

Yes, "Drinks" is a great replacement.

Using the term "shits" in this instance is not an expletive as it defined. The dictionary definition defines it as "vulgar slang" and is easily identifiable as inappropriate for the site.

However merely replacing the term "shits" with the non-vulgar "defecates" destroys the original choice of words to match the idiom "...all it does is shit and eat".
Changing the vulgar "shit" to "drink" is a good change as it retains the matching nature of the example terms without reference to slightly vulgar idioms.

Your concern that the change of the wording destroys the humor that inspires the comment "This example is awesome" is worth thinking about, but the precedent for choosing professionalism over humor has been set

Comment: +1 for using the relevant expletive 4 times.

Comment: I think the OP is not a cat person, as "sleeps" would have been much better.  "drinks" ??? now we have a alcoholic cat.

Comment: "This answer is awesome"

Comment: @Blindman67: my cats drink water. Don't yours?

Answer (score 4):

Shit is not an expletive in this case.  Vulgarity is not banned by the linked post; only expletives.  They are different things.

It is being used in the sense of "poop" or "defecate", not as a swear word.

"Shit" can be used as an expletive; but it not being used as one here.  There is no need to edit it, and editing it makes existing comments and questions make less sense.

Comment: I believe this is just incorrect, or at least not universally correct.  It is profanity where I live and work (American Southwest), even if it is often tolerated.

Comment: @KirkWoll He's not getting hung up on it.  While unnecessary, vulgarity does not break the "no expletives" rule.  Editing it amounts to censorship based on opinion.