# Is this kind of parental advise in the community OK?

Tags: discussion, questions, rules, rude-or-abusive

Should we flag such a question like the following?

*[Compiler does not identify class on the same package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904856/compiler-does-not-identify-class-on-the-same-package)*

Because the OP posted something like (edited by me):

```
System.out.println("random ass shit");
```

Or is this OK since we are all adults and such is not an insult...
Or at least not directed to anybody.

Comment: You already edited it out and solved the problem. I don't think any further action is needed.

Comment: related: [Should I edit the expletives out of a question's code example where the answers reproduce the word?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346486/should-i-edit-the-expletives-out-of-a-questions-code-example-where-the-answers)

Answer (score 17):

You don't need to flag it. There's no indication that the person actually meant any harm by this, so it doesn't need to be investigated by a moderator.

Instead, just edit the question to remove the vulgar phrase. Something like:

```
System.out.println("random string");
```

will do just fine, getting the same point across without the need for coarse language.

(Frankly, I tend to agree that "we are all adults" and this should be okay, but it is [site policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites) to avoid curse words. Furthermore, this particular vulgarity adds absolutely nothing, so you aren't really silencing anyone's voice by redacting it.)

The only time you would need to flag it would be if there was clear indication of foul intent. For example, if the poster had used a racial slur, or if he had included a derogatory remark directed towards a particular user. In that case, you probably would want to flag as "offensive" or alert a moderator so that some type of disciplinary action could be taken.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148327/discussion-on-answer-by-cody-gray-is-this-kind-of-parental-advise-in-the-communi) :)