# Who should edit out obscene/foul words in non-English languages if they are not disapproved as rude/abusive?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, rude-or-abusive, english, obscenity

Today I have detected a post [containing transliterated foul Russian words in the code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62621508/problems-with-saving-and-loading-arraylists-in-2-different-classes-at-the-same-t):

> In "Level1" class I have this:
>
> ```
> private static String[] mudak;  // word #1
> private static String[] pidor;  // word #2
> ArrayList<String> swedish1voc;
> ArrayList<String> english1voc;
> ...
> swedish1voc = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(mudak));
> english1voc = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(pidor));
> ```

Translations:

1. [mudak](https://dictionary.reverso.net/russian-english/%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba)
2. [pidor](http://www.russki-mat.net/page.php?l=RuEn&a=%D0%9F)

I flagged this post as "rude/abusive" and this flag has been declined shortly: *a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it*.

Indeed, the foul language here does not seem to be *harmful* or directed against specific person because it is located in the code snippets.

I looked through available information here on meta and found [similar post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351665/is-this-kind-of-parental-advise-in-the-community-ok/351667#351667).

The answer suggests that expletive words should be edited out, but would not it be more reasonable to require OP to edit out the foul language -- especially if it is not so relevant?

Comment: A rude/abusive flag would have only worked if the mod knew the language. Why did you expect a random mod to be fluent enough on Russian to catch this? Wouldn't a custom flag explaining the situation be more effective?

Comment: Also, you have enough reputation to be able to edit this out. Since the post do not seem to be targeting a specific user, and swift action by a mod is not necessarily warranted, why didn't you just edit the offending words yourself?

Comment: It's the first time for the 2+ months I'm here I encountered such explicit thing, and I was not able to provide any reasoning when I opened a flag - now I see that custom flag would be more appropriate.

Comment: And again, why flag at all? Just edit the words out. This only requires mod intervention if the user rolls back the edits.

Comment: Ok, I edited them out - though I'm convinced that adult people should clean their dirt out by themselves.

Comment: "*I'm convinced that adult people should clean their dirt out by themselves.*" then why did you raise a flag? That requires *another* person to look at it and handle the post. You could have left a comment. Sure, maybe OP should have known better in the first place but they evidently didn't. Without being notified of what to change and why, how is OP to just guess that they need to edit anything?

Comment: @VLAZ I left the comment immediately upon flagging, but OP did not see it was a big deal and he replied: _Maybe it shows how hard java can be for beginners, yet it has nothing to do with my question_

Comment: If the source text is deemed unacceptable because of, say, grossly rude/abusive var names, it would be better/safer to replace ALL the source with some suitable tagline, eg 'rude/abusive text section removed'.  The OP can then redraft with acceptable text.